# Unable to install VLC in Mint

Tags: linux-mint, apt, vlc

Whenever I tried to install VLC player I get the following error:

```
hutber@hutber:~$ sudo apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.4-1~deb8u1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libgles1
       Depends: libvncclient0 (>= 0.9.9) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I then tried to install the dependencies manually.

```
libgles1-mesa:
Depends: libglapi-mesa (=12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but 17.1.0~git20170509+17.1.da13cc7e-0ubuntu0ricotz~16.04.1 is to be installed
```

Why is it that I can't install VLC?

**[Edit]**

```
hutber@hutber:~/vlc-build$ sed -i '/gles1/d' debian/{control,rules,*.install*}
hutber@hutber:~/vlc-build$ dch -n "Drop GLES 1 support (Mesa 17 no longer provides it)."
hutber@hutber:~/vlc-build$ dch -r ignored
hutber@hutber:~/vlc-build$ mk-build-deps
dh_testdir
dh_testroot
dh_prep
dh_testdir
dh_testroot
dh_install
dh_install: Compatibility levels before 9 are deprecated (level 7 in use)
dh_installdocs
dh_installdocs: Compatibility levels before 9 are deprecated (level 7 in use)
dh_installchangelogs
dh_compress
dh_fixperms
dh_installdeb
dh_installdeb: Compatibility levels before 9 are deprecated (level 7 in use)
dh_gencontrol
dh_md5sums
dh_builddeb
dpkg-deb: building package 'vlc-build-deps' in '../vlc-build-deps_2.2.4-1~deb8u1.2_amd64.deb'.

The package has been created.
Attention, the package has been created in the current directory,
not in ".." as indicated by the message above!
hutber@hutber:~/vlc-build$ sudo gdebi vlc-build-deps_*.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done

build-dependencies for vlc
 Dependency package to build the 'vlc' package
Do you want to install the software package? [y/N]:y
(Reading database ... 320548 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack vlc-build-deps_2.2.4-1~deb8u1.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking vlc-build-deps (2.2.4-1~deb8u1.2) over (2.2.4-1~deb8u1.1) ...
Setting up vlc-build-deps (2.2.4-1~deb8u1.2) ...
hutber@hutber:~/vlc-build$ mv vlc-build-deps_*.deb ..
hutber@hutber:~/vlc-build$ dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
dpkg-buildpackage: source package vlc
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 2.2.4-1~deb8u1.2
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution xenial
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Jamie Hutber <hutber@hutber>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 dpkg-source --before-build vlc-build
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean --parallel --with autoreconf
   dh_testdir
   debian/rules override_dh_auto_clean
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/hutber/vlc-build'
rm -f debian/vlc.install debian/vlc-nox.install
dh_auto_clean
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/hutber/vlc-build'
   dh_autoreconf_clean
   dh_clean
 dpkg-source -b vlc-build
dpkg-source: error: can't build with source format '3.0 (quilt)': no upstream tarball found at ../vlc_2.2.4.orig.tar.{bz2,gz,lzma,xz}
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -b vlc-build gave error exit status 255
```

Comment: I take it you have a newer version of Mesa installed from a PPA, is that correct?

Comment: What package sources have you enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have `libglapi-mesa` version 17 installed, I’m guessing you’ve updated Mesa from some other repository than the Mint defaults. Mesa 17 dropped GLES1 support, but the VLC packages are built with a dependency on GLES1, so you can’t install the VLC packages with Mesa.

You can however build your own VLC packages without GLES1:

- Install the basic build tools and some utilities we’re about to use:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install build-essential devscripts equivs gdebi
  ```
- Go to a directory in which you can write

  ```
  cd
  mkdir vlc-build
  cd vlc-build
  ```
- Download the VLC packages’ source

  ```
  apt-get source vlc
  ```

  or, if your repositories’ configuration doesn’t allow that to work,

  ```
  dget http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/v/vlc/vlc_2.2.4-1~deb8u1.dsc
  ```

  (which matches the version you have in Mint)
- In the extracted directory (`vlc-2.2.4` probably), edit a few files:

  ```
  sed -i '/gles1/d' debian/{control,rules,*.install*}
  ```
- Still in the extracted directory, run the following to update the changelog and produce a new version (so your private version won’t be replaced by the existing version):

  ```
  dch -n "Drop GLES 1 support (Mesa 17 no longer provides it)."
  dch -r ignored
  ```
- Install the build dependencies (unfortunately you can’t use `apt-get build-dep vlc` because you can’t install the GLES 1 libraries):

  ```
  mk-build-deps
  sudo gdebi vlc-build-deps_*.deb
  mv vlc-build-deps_*.deb ..
  ```

  (this last step moves the generated dependency package out of the way)
- Build the package:

  ```
  dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
  ```
- Now you can install whichever packages you need, you’ll find them in the parent directory:

  ```
  ls ../*.deb
  ```

You’ll now need to keep an eye on future updates to VLC (which happen sometimes, to fix security issues in particular) and repeat the process whenever necessary.

Comment: Amazing, thank you for this. Now I need to just find where the source for VLC is stored as it doesn't exist in my apt

Comment: @Jamie I’ve added instructions to work around that.

Comment: Hey Stephen, a very long delay :) But I've updated the question with my console load results of your steps. Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: You need to change to the extracted directory (“in the extracted directory” in the instructions above), probably `cd vlc-2.2.4`.

Comment: Ah yes, I had actually followed this :) `hutber@hutber:~/vlc-build/vlc-2.2.4$ sed -i '/gles1/d' debian/{control,rules,*.install*}
sed: can't read debian/control: No such file or directory
sed: can't read debian/rules: No such file or directory
sed: can't read debian/*.install*: No such file or directory
`

Comment: The reason I stayed in the original `dir` as I saw `debian` folder `hutber@hutber:~/vlc-build$ ll
total 21764` - 
`drwxr-xr-x  4 hutber hutber     4096 May 26 21:58 ./` -
`drwxr-xr-x 87 hutber hutber     4096 Sep 18 09:50 ../`-
`drwxr-xr-x  4 hutber hutber     4096 May 26 19:42 debian/`-
`drwxr-xr-x  8 hutber hutber     4096 May 26 19:26 vlc-2.2.4/`-
`-rw-r--r--  1 hutber hutber    58632 May 17 23:06 vlc_2.2.4--1~deb8u1.debian.tar.xz`
`-rw-r--r--  1 hutber hutber     5410 May 26 21:58 vlc_2.2.4-1~deb8u1.dsc`-
`-rw-r--r--  1 hutber hutber 22199316 May 17 23:06 vlc_2.2.4.orig.tar.xz`

Comment: Could you try again after deleting `~/vlc-build`? After `apt-get source ...`, you should end up with `~/vlc-build/vlc-2.2.4` containing the `debian` directory, and no `debian` directory in `~/vlc-build` itself.